# spacy componente no exporta la función C esperada hash128_x86

Tags: python, python-2.7

Intenté ejecutar `app.py`, un archivo que viene de [esto repositorio](https://github.com/shaildeliwala/delbot/blob/master/app.py) , pero tuve un problema con la importación de QueryService, que depende de SpaCy. Dice que :

```
    from .optimizers import Adam, SGD, linear_decay
  File "optimizers.pyx", line 13, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "ops.pyx", line 1, in init thinc.neural.ops
ImportError: murmurhash.mrmr does not export expected C function hash128_x86
```

Penso que el programador debería haber agregado los requisitos. Quizás esté relacionado, quizás no.

```
(delbot_env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ python2 app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 20, in <module>
    from resources.query_service import QueryService
  File "/home/mike/Programming/delbot/resources/query_service.py", line 22, in <module>
    import query_extractor as _qe
  File "/home/mike/Programming/delbot/query_extractor.py", line 20, in <module>
    import spacy as _s
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .link import link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 9, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import copy_array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, SGD, linear_decay
  File "optimizers.pyx", line 13, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "ops.pyx", line 1, in init thinc.neural.ops
ImportError: murmurhash.mrmr does not export expected C function hash128_x86
```

#### versions:

OS : Linux 16.04

Python: 2.7.12

Obtuve el mismo error que por encima cuando intento tener información sobre SpaCy:

```
(.delbot_env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ python2 -m spacy info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(mod_name)  # Do not catch exceptions initializing package
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .link import link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 9, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import copy_array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, SGD, linear_decay
  File "optimizers.pyx", line 13, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "ops.pyx", line 1, in init thinc.neural.ops
ImportError: murmurhash.mrmr does not export expected C function hash128_x86
```

Installo SpaCy en un entorno virual para Python 2.7, porque parece que el repositorio esta escrito para Python 2.7, de la manera siguiente desde [el sitio de SpaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/):

```
python -m pip install -U virtualenv
virtualenv .delbot_env
source .delbot_env/bin/activate
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

#### 24/07

Créé un nuevo entorno totalmente limpio

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ virtualenv --no-site-packages .delbot_env2
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/mike/Programming/delbot/.delbot_env2/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/mike/Programming/delbot/.delbot_env2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Y actualicé `pip` y `wheel`

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ source .delbot_env2/bin/activate(.delbot_env2) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ pip install --upgrade pip wheel
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.delbot_env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages (18.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in ./.delbot_env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.31.1)
```

Instalé SpaCy :

```
(.delbot_env2) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ pip install spacy
Collecting spacy
Collecting ujson>=1.35 (from spacy)
Collecting murmurhash<0.29,>=0.28 (from spacy)
Collecting numpy>=1.7 (from spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/b9/479ccb55cc7dcff3d4fc7c8c26d4887846875e7d4f04483a36f335bed712/numpy-1.15.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting preshed<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from spacy)
Collecting dill<0.3,>=0.2 (from spacy)
Collecting cymem<1.32,>=1.30 (from spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/43/39372a0bc24d336dc88b87262c30f09d0a2c759f32a2965f90fb56da46f1/cymem-1.31.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 (from spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting regex==2017.4.5 (from spacy)
Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3 (from spacy)
Collecting urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/c9/6fdd990019071a4a32a5e7cb78a1d92c53851ef4f56f62a3486e6a7d8ffb/urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e6/92ad559b7192d846975fc916b65f667c7b8c3a32bea7372340bfe9a15fa5/certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5 (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting msgpack<1.0.0,>=0.5.6 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/08/72/5a01d2a6a894e7f6966b0038445c748d7a16754cceb0e988699269d8152a/msgpack-0.5.6-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/24/6ab1df969db228aed36a648a8959d1027099ce45fad67532b9673d533318/tqdm-4.23.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six<2.0.0,>=1.10.0 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting msgpack-numpy<1.0.0,>=0.4.1 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/09/fc890664a7a1dd0a88f46c93fb9340d0a27a69e82095a4a54aef2ed94a6d/msgpack_numpy-0.4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cytoolz<0.10,>=0.9.0 (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
Collecting toolz>=0.8.0 (from cytoolz<0.10,>=0.9.0->thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy)
Installing collected packages: ujson, murmurhash, numpy, cymem, preshed, dill, urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna, requests, regex, plac, msgpack, wrapt, tqdm, six, msgpack-numpy, toolz, cytoolz, thinc, spacy
Successfully installed certifi-2018.4.16 chardet-3.0.4 cymem-1.31.2 cytoolz-0.9.0.1 dill-0.2.8.2 idna-2.7 msgpack-0.5.6 msgpack-numpy-0.4.3.1 murmurhash-0.28.0 numpy-1.15.0 plac-0.9.6 preshed-1.0.1 regex-2017.4.5 requests-2.19.1 six-1.11.0 spacy-2.0.12 thinc-6.10.3 toolz-0.9.0 tqdm-4.23.4 ujson-1.35 urllib3-1.23 wrapt-1.10.11
(.delbot_env2) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ import spacy
```

Sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar:

```
(.delbot_env2) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ python2 app.py Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 20, in <module>
    from resources.query_service import QueryService
  File "/home/mike/Programming/delbot/resources/query_service.py", line 22, in <module>
    import query_extractor as _qe
  File "/home/mike/Programming/delbot/query_extractor.py", line 20, in <module>
    import spacy as _s
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .link import link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/link.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..compat import symlink_to, path2str
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacy/compat.py", line 9, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import copy_array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thinc/neural/train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, SGD, linear_decay
  File "optimizers.pyx", line 13, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "ops.pyx", line 1, in init thinc.neural.ops
ImportError: murmurhash.mrmr does not export expected C function hash128_x86
```

#### Actualizacion

La ruta esta :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ source .delbot_env2/bin/activate
(.delbot_env2) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ python app.py
  File "app.py", line 53
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Sabe que el interprete `python` esta Python 3.5.2 vesion pero intenté ejecutar el script con `python app.py`.

```
(.delbot_env2) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/delbot$ python app.py
  File "app.py", line 53
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Y por conclueir `/usr/bin/python2 app.py` da la misma `ImportError̀  que los otros intentos.

Comment: @abulafia Perdoneme ^^ el español no es mi lengua materna :p.
Gracias para la referencia pero ¿OSX esta para Mac no? utiliso Linux. ¿Funcionaría de todos modos?

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias FJ, agregué la forma en que instalé SpaCy y los problemas que encuentro cuando trato de obtener su versión.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias, entonces esto es extraño porque codigo desde una computadora con Linux. Utilisaba pip. Agregué los comandos que utilicé

Comment: Quizás no tenías instalado `python2.7-dev` (necesario cuando instalas paquetes Python que tienen componentes en C y deben ser compilados) y entonces la instalación de SpaCy te dio errores.

Comment: @abulafia De acuerdo, voy a buscar en línea cómo hacerlo. Este es el mas simple?

Comment: Aparte del último comentario de Abulafia, parece que lo tenias instalado en el sistema antes de crear el entorno virtual porque las rutas son a "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" no a la localización de tu entorno. Para descartar cosas yo crearía un nuevo entorno pero  totalmente limpio  `virtualenv --no-site-packages delbot_env2`,  activalo con `source .delbot_env2/bin/activate` , actualiza pip y wheel por si acaso (`pip install --upgrade pip wheel`) e instala `pip install spacy`. Tras esto prueba `import spacy`. Si sigue sin funcionar comenta a ver si cython  compiló bien `murmurhash`.

Comment: @Marine1 En tu última actualización, olvidaste poner el punto inicial en el nombre del entorno virtual, al crearlo (tal punto no es necesario, pero si no lo pones, entonces tampoco lo uses al activarlo).

Comment: @FJSevilla Muchas gracias FJ. Todavia, sigue sin funcionar, creo que estoy maldito

Comment: Marine1 yo no creo en la magia negra...XD. Si te fijas sigues usando "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/".... Con tu entorno virtual activado, el nuevo, ingresa  `python2` en la terminal  y en el intérprete interactivo  `import sys ` y luego ingresas  `sys.executable `, muestra la ruta. Por otro lado intenta  ejecutar tu script con  `python app.py ` no con python2, si tampoco funciona llama directamente al interprete de tu entorno virtual, pasando la ruta explícita por ejem. (mira donde tienes la carpeta de tu entorno .delbot_env2) `/home/Programming/delbot/.delbot_env2/bin/python app.py`

Comment: @FJSevilla, Hola FJ! Lo intenté, desafortunadamente no sucede. Por cierto, no hay `app.py` en `.delbot_env2 /`, solo cosas como `spacy`, `wheel`,`__pycache__`, `pip` ...

Comment: Marine1, el problema es que **el entorno que has creado es para Python3** ("New python executable in /home/mike/Programming/delbot/.delbot_env2/bin/ **python3**") y la culpa fue en parte mía por no ser explícito. Esto pasa porque has seguido lo que dice en la web de SpaCy pero sin tener en cuenta que `$ python` en tu caso enlaza a Python3 pero tu quieres usar un entorno con Python2.  Cuando haces `python app.py` el error es de sintaxis (porque es código para Python 2). Logicamente `python2 app.py` usa `/usr/bin/python2` porque tu entorno es de Python3.

Comment: Repite los pasos pero haciendo lo siguiente: `python2 -m pip install -U virtualenv` -> 
`python2 -m virtualenv --no-site-packages delbot_env3` ->
`source delbot_env3/bin/activate` -> `pip install --upgrade pip wheel`  ->
`pip install spacy` -> `python app.py`. Si no te funciona actualiza la pregunta y agrega la salida de todo el proceso anterior como hiciste en la última actualización.

Comment: Lo siento FJ, lo siento, lo entiendo rápidamente, pero tengo que explicarlo lentamente :p ¡Muchas gracias! También logré transformar el código en Python3. Pero ya sea este código en Python2 o el que modifiqué un poco en Python3, tengo el mismo problema en ambos casos: Cuando hago clic en el botón Consulta que se agrega que inicia el reconocimiento de voz, no tengo ninguna reacción. He puesto una pregunta para esto [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183528/no-hay-reacci%c3%b3n-cuando-clic-en-el-bot%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el entorno que creé es para Python3 ("New python executable in /home/mike/Programming/delbot/.delbot_env2/bin/ python3"). Esto pasa porque segui lo que dice en la web de SpaCy pero sin tener en cuenta que `$ python` en mi caso enlaza a Python3 pero quiero usar un entorno con Python2. Cuando haces `python app.py` el error es de sintaxis (porque es código para Python 2). Logicamente `python2 app.py` usa `/usr/bin/python2` porque mi entorno es de Python3.

Finalmente hice los siguientes pasos pero haciendo lo siguiente: `python2 -m pip install -U virtualenv` -> `python2 -m virtualenv --no-site-packages delbot_env3` -> `source delbot_env3/bin/activate` -> `pip install --upgrade pip wheel` -> `pip install spacy` -> `python app.py`