# No hay reacción cuando clic en el botón

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask

Tengo un archivo `templates/index.html`. Cuando hace une clic sobre el primero botton, `btn_query`, deberia llamar a `startDictation()`, una funcion javascript para reconocimiento de voz.  Pero hay un problema, que solo aparece sobre stackoverflow y con Chrome, con `recognition.onresult = function (e){...}`.

1. No obtenemos el pop-up `window.alert(5 + 6);` al comienzo de la función
2. la consola Stavkoverflow reconoce que hay un error y escribe: `Recognition had an error`. Pero no sé cuál.

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html style="margin: auto; display:table;">
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
       </script>
       <script>var synth = window.speechSynthesis;</script>
       <!-- HTML5 Speech Recognition API -->
       <script>
               function startDictation() {
                   document.getElementById('transcript').value = '';
                   document.getElementById('output').value = '';
                   if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {
                       var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                       recognition.continuous = false;
                       recognition.interimResults = false;
                       recognition.lang = "en-US";
                       recognition.start();
                       recognition.onresult = function (e) {
                           window.alert(5 + 6);
                           document.getElementById('loader').hidden = false;
                           document.getElementById('transcript').value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
                           recognition.stop();
                           var data = e.results[0][0].transcript;
                           $.post("http://localhost:5000/news_urls", { "data": data },
                           function (response) {
                           document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
                               data = response;
                               document.getElementById("output").value = data["urls"];
                           }).error(function (response) {
                           document.getElementById('loader').hidden = true;
                               if (response.status == 400)
                                   text = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText)["original_exception"];
                               else
                                   text = "I'm sorry. I did not get that.";
                               document.getElementById("output").value = text;
                           });
                       };
                       recognition.onerror = function (e) {
                           recognition.stop();
                           console.log("Recognition had an error");
                       }
                   }
               }

               function btnClick() {
                    synth.cancel();
                       var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.getElementById("output").value);
                       utterThis.voice = synth.getVoices()[0];
                       utterThis.pitch = 1.0;
                       utterThis.rate = 0.8;
                       utterThis.onerror = function(e) { console.log("Something went wrong with utterance."); };
                       synth.speak(utterThis);
               }
       </script>
       <style>
           .speech {
               border: 0px solid #DDD;
               width: 600px;
               padding: 0;
               margin: 0;
               font-family: "Calibri";
           }

               .speech input {
                   border: 1;
                   width: 240px;
                   display: inline-block;
                   height: 30px;
               }

               .speech img {
                   float: right;
                   width: 40px;
               }
       </style>
   </head>

   <body bgcolor="#e2e2e2">
       <h1 style="font-family: Calibri;">Delbot</h1>
       <div class="speech" ><i>It understands your voice commands, searches news and knowledge sources, and summarizes and reads out content to you.</i></div>
       <br /><i class="speech"><font color="gray">Only tested on Windows PCs. Not tested on other PCs or mobile devices.</font></i>

       <div class="speech">
               <textarea style="width: 600px;font-family: Calibri;font-size:x-large" name="q" id="transcript"
                         placeholder="Your query will appear here after you speak." rows="2" readonly="True"></textarea>
               <br>
               <input id="btn_query" type="button" onclick="startDictation()" value="Query"
                      style="font-family: Calibri;" />
               <img src="static/loader.gif" width="100px" align="left" style="float: left" hidden="True" id="loader" />
               <br><br>
               <h2 class="speech">Results</h2>
               <textarea style="width: 600px;font-family: Calibri;font-size:x-large" id="output" rows="2" placeholder="Results will appear here."
                         readonly="True"></textarea>
               <input id="btn_speak" type="button" value="Speak" onclick="btnClick()" style="font-family: Calibri;" />

       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Puedes poner el Script en el head ?

Comment: ¿Marine1 qué navegador web estas usando?

Comment: @FJSevilla Firefox !

Comment: @LucianoMontañez ! Si por seguro, pero no cambia el resultado

Comment: Robe el código y de hecho, si me ejecuta el window.alert(5 + 6);

Comment: Prueba con Chrome  por ejemplo, `if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition'))` nunca se va a cumplir en Firefox (`SpeechRecognition`) si no me equivoco (no es mi campo y no estoy muy al día ...XD)... el código tal como está no es compatible con Firefox, en principio no es problema de Python o Flask.

Comment: @FJSevilla ! Bien visto ! El texto no aparece pero parece reaccionar en Chrome. Me pregunto si [esta alternativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) me permitiría tenerla en ambos motores de búsqueda

Comment: @LucianoMontañez Demasiado extrano! No tengo nada aquí en stackoverflow. En el localhost no tengo nada de nada con Chrome o Firefox

Comment: @LucianoMontañez, Descubrí que fue un error, por un lado, modifiqué la copia del archivo y no el archivo en sí. Actualicé el código porque cuando trato de recuperar el texto utilizado por `recognition.onresult = function (e)`, parece que no entro en la función porque no tengo el pop-up

Answer (score 2):

Antes de nada, por favor usa HTTPS para referenciar a JQuery (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)

El método startDictation es invocado en cualquier navegador, esto incluye Firefox. Tu problema es el siguiente:

```
if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {
    ...
}
```

Solamente se entrará en este if si window tiene definido webkitSpeechRecognition. Esto nos lleva a la Web Speech API.

La API en cuestión está clasificada como experimental. Si un usuario quiere usarla en Firefox debe modificar la configuración del navegador como puedes ver en la web oficial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Además, estás llamando a la API con prefijo (webKit) cuando deberías comprobar primero si existe la propiedad sin prefijo (SpeechRecognition) y hacer uso de ella si es así.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Quizas a lo mejor algo así:    `window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;` y luego:    `if (window.SpeechRecognition) {...}`

Comment: @DamianGarcia por supuesto, pero la API sigue siendo experimental y en firefox el cliente debe habilitar un flag. Esta funcionalidad será increíble cuando sea estándar :)

Comment: Es verdad, yo estoy haciendo algo también para mi sitio y sólo me funciona en Chrome. En firefox, Edge, IE...nada de nada y en Opera me sale un mensaje _"Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started."_ No sé que pasa con Safari.